# Rails - How to Verify User Attributes Before Login

Tags: ruby-on-rails, authlogic

I am using Authlogic and net-ldap to authenticate users to Active Directory in my new Rails 4 app.  Works nicely...

However, I would like to import all users from another database so they don't have to create their accounts from scratch (and, because each user must select another user as his supervisor to complete his profile - and it turns into a chicken-egg kind of problem if I start with an empty users table).  There are required fields in my new users table that are not in the source user table, so I want to force users to complete their profiles upon initial login, before they can get into the app.

Is there a way I can maybe do a before_create user_session validation on `login_count is null` or something like that?  Is there a better way to handle this sort of thing?

Any suggestions are appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would add a field to users table called `completed_profile` of boolean type:

`rails g add_completed_profile_to_users completed_profile:boolean`

then create a filter method in **application_controller.rb**

```
  def complete_profile
    if current_user.completed_profile?
      redirect_to the_path_after_log_in
    else
      redirect_to edit_profile_path, error: "Please update your profile."
    end
  end
```

*field_one and field_two are the required fields to fill in before proceeding to app.*

In other controller of your app:

```
before_filter :complete_profile
```

this filter should not be applied to controller and action that responds for rendering the edit profile page or new account page, if `edit_profile_path = users#edit` means in users controller your filter will look like:

```
before_filter :complete_profile, except: ['edit', 'update', 'new', 'create']
```

---

**variant 2**, without migration:

create a filter method in **application_controller.rb**

```
  def complete_profile
    if current_user.field_one.present? && current_user.field_two.present?
      redirect_to the_path_after_log_in
    else
      redirect_to edit_profile_path, error: "Please update your field_one and field_two."
    end
  end
```

in other controller of your app:

```
before_filter :complete_profile
```

Comment: Good idea, thanks for your suggestion!  How does it know what a completed profile is, though?  Don't I have to indicate what user fields constitute a completed profile?

Comment: you can write a method probably that will check for all required fields and when user will be redirected to edit_profile_path a message will display what fields exactly are missing.